# Only some Font Awesome icons display

Tags: blazor, font-awesome, blazorise

Only *some* icons work:

- fa-user
- fa-check
- fa-minus
- fa-phone

Others just show an empty square icon:

- fa-skull
- fa-apple

and others don't do anything:

- fa-x
- fa-xmark
- fa-road-circle-exclamation

I'm using Blazor with Blazorize, and have tried the following:

- `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` (works)
- `<i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>` (doesn't work)
- `<Icon Name="IconName.Mail" />` (works)
- `<Icon Name="@("fa-gift")" />` (works)
- `<Icon Name="@("fa-xmark")" />` (doesn't work)
- `<Icon Name="@("fa-xmark")" IconStyle="IconStyle.Solid" />` (doesn't work)

In my _Host.cshtml file I have:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" />`

Without which the Blazorize `<Icon>` method never works.

Comment: The non-working icons appear to be from the "pro" (paid) set of icons.  So this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @Roberto xmark is free and doesn't work

Comment: @Vereonix xmark does not seem to be included in v5

Comment: The most case that Font Awesome didn't work. 1. Use wrong version. 2. Use PRO icons while you don't have PRO access. 3. Use incorrect class name. (Not just typo incorrectly but sometime users use incorrect name from different version.)

Comment: fa-xmark does not work for me, only fa-check works for me

Comment: Try fa-x or fa-close instead of fa-xmark

Answer (score 3):

**Solution - Upgrade to Font Awesome 6**

The icons, such as "xmark", do not work because they are not included in the Font Awesome version 5 free icon set. And the question specifically asks about version 5 by including a link.  The possible solutions are (1) don't use missing icons or (2) upgrade to Font Awesome 6.

And as an aside, Bootstrap 5 now has its own quite extensive set of icons which can be found here:

[Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

My quick work around is use fa-close to replace fa-xmark

I am using bootstrap 5, fa-xmark not working, only fa-check works sometimes.

see example my example below orange icon and green icon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use "times" in version 5 for "xmark" and "x"

https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/times?s=solid&f=classic

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [xmark icons are available only in 6.2.0 version which is paid](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/setup/get-started). I have found a workaround: you can download .svg file of the icon you like and use it in your project with help of `<img>` tag. You will lose some fancy functionality like easy customization but it still works.